# Call WebApi method, Error 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, api

Im having a problem with a `WebMethod` `MVC`
This is the  method in the controller

```
[HttpPost]        
public IHttpActionResult GetData(int Company,
    int FromYear,int ToYear, int language ,
    int DATA_SERIES_TYPE, bool PERIOD_Q1)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        ds = Actions.GetValues(Company, FromYear, ToYear,DATA_SERIES_TYPE);
        return Ok(ds);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

I have this method in an API, when i call the api from another project using webrequest

```
Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/PBWebApi/api/GetData")
With strJson
    .Append("{")
    .Append($"Company:{_dynaSolver.CompanyCode.ToString()}" & ",")
    .Append($"FromYear:{_dynaSolver.FromYear.ToString}" & ",")
    .Append($"ToYear:{_dynaSolver.ToYear.ToString}" & ",")
    .Append($"language:{CType(_dynaSolver.DataLanguage, Integer).ToString}" & ",")
    .Append($"DATA_SERIES_TYPE:{ CType(_dynaSolver.Fundamentals, Integer).ToString}")
    .Append("}")
End With

Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJson.ToString)
With Request
    .Method = "POST"
    .ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    .ContentLength = data.Length
End With

Dim stream = Request.GetRequestStream()
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
stream.Close()

Dim response = Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response)
Dim res = reader.ReadToEnd()
dsRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(res)
reader.Close()
response.Close()
```

When i execute this, the response gives this error.

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

I tried using just one parameter in another function but i got the same result.
I tried using fiddler but i got the same error.

Comment: Are you running it from IDE or IIS? If from IDE don't you need the port in the URI?

Comment: Hi, i tried running from the IIS but i get the same error so i running the api from iisexpress to try catch it, but the call never enters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem creating and object called id and adding all the properties to that object.
After that i send the object as json in the content and it works.
Regards